# shortest path for three coordinates with random order

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, algorithm, mapbox

**update 1:**

Hi, I found one more fiddle and I tried with a few locations, when I give los angeles as starting. It should have given san jose as the second coordinate. But it provided wrong results. Can you let me know how to fix it or can you suggest some other algorithm?

https://jsfiddle.net/byopz23k/3/

Using the below link I am able to achive map box directions in my code base.
Is it possible to find the shortest route when we give more than three coordinates in random order using mapbox api or do we need to use Dijkstra’s Algorithm. Providing code snippet below, can you let us know how to proceed

**but for random order it's giving different distances, in that I need to choose the shortest distance**

distance: 131650.609 duration: 5756.365

distance: 83112.961 duration: 4010.865

https://www.letsreact.org/use-mapbox-gl-js-in-a-react-app/

```
const showRoute = async (start: [number, number], end: [number, number]) => {
    const middlePaloAlto = [-122.1430, 37.4419];
    const query = await fetch(
      `https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving/${start[0]},${start[1]};${middlePaloAlto[0]},${middlePaloAlto[1]};${end[0]},${end[1]}?steps=true&geometries=geojson&access_token=${mapboxgl.accessToken}`,
      { method: 'GET' }
    );

    const json = await query.json();
    // console.log("alv json", json);
    const data = json.routes[0];
    const route = data.geometry.coordinates;
    return {
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {},
      geometry: {
        type: 'LineString',
        'coordinates': route
      },
      duration: data.duration,
      distance: data.distance

    };
  }
```